# Elixir: How do I check if an element exists in a specific index of a tuple in an array?

Tags: tuples, elixir

For example,

```
[
  {1, 3, "1S"},
  {3, 3, "3S"},
  {9, 3, "9S"},
  {10, 3, "10S"},
  {11, 3, "11S"},
  {12, 3, "12S"},
  {13, 3, "13S"}
]
```

I would like to check if 10 exists in all 0-th index for each tuple. Is there a built in function for this, or do I have to iterate through each tupe to check for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no *arrays* in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) in the first place. There are only lists, implemented as [*Linked Lists*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list).

Tuples cannot be iterated, they can only be pattern-matched against, converted to lists, or directly accesses with [`Kernel.elem/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#elem/2).

Whether you want to check *all* elements, you are to iterate through all elements, even if you had an array.

That said, there is [`Enum.all?/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#all?/2) function, that would nevertheless iterate the list under the hood, but the notation would be simpler.

```rb
input =
  [
    {1, 3, "1S"},
    {10, 3, "10S"}
  ]

Enum.all?(input, &match?({10, _, _}, &1))
#⇒ false
Enum.all?(input, &match?({_, 3, _}, &1))
#⇒ true

# or, with elem/2
Enum.all?(input, &elem(&1, 0) == 10)
#⇒ false
Enum.all?(input, &elem(&1, 1) == 3) 
#⇒ true
```

---

[`Kernel.match?/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#match?/2).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on arrays, linked lists and tuples! Just to clarify, what is the parameter `&1` mean? 

I'm also confused with the boolean results from the `Enum.all?` function. Is the function checking if ALL elements in the first parameter pattern matched to 10 in ({10, _, _,})? Hence, why ({_,3,_}) gave true, whereas ({10,_,_}) gave false because the first only had 1 element as 10? My goal was to see if at least any in the first parameter matches 10. Perhaps I should explore `Enum.any?`

Comment: `&1` in [anonymous captures](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#&/1) refers to the first parameter of the function. `{_, 3, _}` returns `true` because I pattern match against the second tuple element (this is just an example.) If you want to check whether _any_ fits, use `Enum.any?/2`, the question stated you want to check for all (_“10 exists in **all** 0-th index for each tuple”_.)

Comment: Also, you might want to check [`Enum.filter/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#filter/2) having nearly the same semantics, but returning the filtered list back instead of `boolean()`.

Comment: Curiously, I understand that tuples cannot be iterated directly, but suppose there is a list of tuples. Could one not iterate each element in the list, which is a tuple, then use `elem(tuple, 0)` to iterate for elements in the 0th element of every tuple in the list?

For example, consider `Enum.map(input, fn x -> elem(x, 0) end)` , which returns a list containing every 0th element for each tuple from the input list of tuples

Comment: I am sorry, I do not follow. The examples I posted do exactly this: they check the `n-th` element of each tuple to match the condition.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. You are correct in that my question did not accurately represent my intentions, apologies! Yet, this was still an informative response. I will be using `Enum.any?/2`, cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`:lists.keymember/3`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#keymember-3).  It takes three arguments:

1. The element you're looking for
2. The position in the tuple to look for it in (1-based)
3. The list of tuples

```
iex(1)> x = [     
...(1)>   {1, 3, "1S"},
...(1)>   {3, 3, "3S"},
...(1)>   {9, 3, "9S"},
...(1)>   {10, 3, "10S"},
...(1)>   {11, 3, "11S"},
...(1)>   {12, 3, "12S"},
...(1)>   {13, 3, "13S"}
...(1)> ]
[
  {1, 3, "1S"},
  {3, 3, "3S"},
  {9, 3, "9S"},
  {10, 3, "10S"},
  {11, 3, "11S"},
  {12, 3, "12S"},
  {13, 3, "13S"}
]
iex(2)> :lists.keymember(10, 1, x)
true
iex(3)> :lists.keymember(8, 1, x) 
false
iex(4)> :lists.keymember("1S", 3, x)
true
iex(5)> :lists.keymember("2S", 3, x)
false
```

Comment: Wow, that's very concise, thank you so much!!! I find this notation much more readable.